# Using dictionary in LINQ Where clause

Tags: c#, sql, performance, linq, dictionary

I have a list of data called `DataList`. `DataList` is having field `id` and `UpdatedTime` and some other fields. On the other, I have a dictionary with just the `id` and its respective value `UpdatedTime`.
Is there any way to filter DataList such that it satisfies the dictionary `itemIdAndUpdatedTimeFilter` item Id and their respective `UpdatedTime` is higher than that of the `DataList`'s `UpdatedTime`?

```
Dictionary<int, DateTime> itemIdAndUpdatedTimeFilter = getFilter();
itemIdAndUpdatedTimeFilter.Add(1, dateA);
itemIdAndUpdatedTimeFilter.Add(2, dateB);
itemIdAndUpdatedTimeFilter.Add(3, dateC);

var dataList = getData();

var filtered = dataList.Where(d=>itemIdAndUpdatedTimeFilter.ContainsKey(d.Id) && itemIdAndUpdatedTimeFilter[d.Id] < d.UpdatedTime)
```

The above LINQ statement ended up in following exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean
>   ContainsKey(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into
>   a store expression.

Tried deleted the `ContainKey` condition and get the following instead:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime
>   get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression.

Desired query is such that:

```
SELECT FROM dataList
WHERE (dataList.UpdatedTime < dateA AND dataList.Id = 1)
OR (dataList.UpdatedTime < dateB AND dataList.Id = 2)
OR (dataList.UpdatedTime < dateC AND dataList.Id = 3)
```

Comment: You can't use a dictionary to filter a database table, that is not translatable into a sql store expression. Or is the example sql only the comparable syntax for an in memory filter?

Comment: @Igor I see, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch all items from the database and filter the *in-memory* results:

```
var dataList = getData().ToList();
var filtered = dataList.Where(d=>itemIdAndUpdatedTimeFilter.ContainsKey(d.I‌​d) && itemIdAndUpdatedTimeFilter[d.Id] > d.UpdateTime)):
```

The other option would be to execute raw SQL or a stored procedure that performs the filtering in the database: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx

Entity Framework won't be able to translate your filtering logic into a valid SQL query.